# Multiple predictors in a correlation analysis?

Tags: r, correlation

I would like to run a correlation analysis to ask whether the concentrations of certain secondary compounds are correlated across tissues within individuals in a plant species. However, a linear model including total concentrations and sites revealed a significant site effect. Is there a way to run a single correlation analysis (using
     corr()
or similar) that includes more than one type of predictor?

Is there a way to include multiple predictors in a correlation analysis in the corr() function? If not, is there a similar function that will take multiple predictors?

Comment: Are you interested in [partial correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=partial+correlation)?

Comment: I recommend the classes on DATACAMP Quantitative Analysis career track. I'm currently learning how to do the issue you just described. Good luck!